# how to get the data from inputs in the next page reactjs

Tags: reactjs, input

I'm building a react js website that has three pages of inputs
the last page should have all the data entered in the previous pages
it will be a summary of the data

for the first three pages i have been using use state and handle submit in order to show the data in the console log

now I want to gather all the data on one page and it should be displayed on the last page
not in the console log

what technique should I be using?

Answer (score 1):

**option 1** :
in each page, save your data to localstorage and in the last page get your data from local storage (then delete it from local storage).

**option 2**:

pass your data as props; pass data from first page to second page then pass data of the first page and second page to third page....

Comment: thank u for ur answer,
how about using useForm?
how can i get the data after using it in my first 3 pages